# APIs and tools for google-drive in c++/qt

Tags: c++, api, qt

Are there any API's for google-drive in C++/Qt OR Any tool like Insync which is free for use and can be used for accessing and managing on google-drive.
I have tried using qt-google-drive by ics but it's still under development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Drive from essentially anything that can generate HTTP requests (and, obviously, use the reply data).

The [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/) doesn't include any examples written in C++, but as you can see in the [reference section](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), it's all done with fairly normal HTTP GETs, POSTs, etc.

Comment: Jerry Coffin I came across kqoauth which has an example for twitter.Can it be used for google-drive upload.If yes then how since I cannot understand how I would manage redirected url part as given in google-drive sdk quickstart examples

Comment: I've never tried kqoauth, so I'm afraid I can't really tell you much about whether (and if so, how) it'll work. Sorry.